# UnauthorizedAccessException for static files when using IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I am developing a web application using ASP.Net core MVC. Initially to get started I manually copied the bootstrap and jQuery directly under wwwroot/lib folder. This worked fine.

To make the code maintainable, I thought it would be better to use client side library manager like libman.
This is what I have got in libman.json

```js
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "unpkg",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "bootstrap@4.1.3",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/"
    },
    {
      "provider": "cdnjs",
      "library": "jquery@3.3.1",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery/"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I restore the client side library, I can see the files correctly restored under lib folder

Now when I compile and test the app locally using IIS, I am getting 500 error in developer tools while fetching bootstrap.css, jquery.js and bootstrap.js

When I tried to load bootstrap.css directly, I get 500 and message that access to the file is denied

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\code\wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css' is denied.
```

Any thoughts what would be causing this error?

Comment: The IIS app pool account user needs to have access to the files. Check the file permissions.

Comment: Thanks Poke. When I add the files manually they work fine. This problem only occurs when I remove the manually added files and use restore client libraries which then adds the file files and compiles the css file at build time.

Comment: I checked the permission and the application pool account has the permission on css folder

Comment: Did you check the _files_ too?

Comment: ah...strange. Even through at folder level it is showing that these permissions applies to folders, subfolders and files, the files itself dont have the permissions. Thanks poke. I will investigate

Comment: Thanks Poke. Sorting out the permissions on the files fixes the issue